# How to get vim spell check to mark bad words inside of Latex math equations?

Tags: vim, latex, spell-checking

Spell check in vim is nice enough to not highlight things inside of a math environment when writing LaTeX. This is convenient, but I make some very common typos like "theat" instead of "theta" that would be nice to catch automatically. Is there a way to get the words in the explicit list of 'bad words' to be highlighted regardless of their context?

Note that I still don't want to check whether everything is good within a math environment, just that it is not explicitly bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable spell checking for a syntax group, you'd have to add `contains=@Spell`, e.g. for the `texStatement` group, that would be:

```
:syn match texStatement "\\\a\+" contains=@Spell
```

But with that, you'd still have to add all "good" statements to your spell file. If you just want to highlight certain "bad" words, you can define a contained match:

```
:syn match texBadStatement "theat" containedin=texStatement
```

And then link to the error or bad spell highlighting:

```
:hi link texBadStatement SpellBad
```

Put those commands into `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` to make them persistent.

I'm not a Latex specialist. If the `texStatement` group is wrong, you need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going with just using vim's abbr commands to fix the most glaring typos automatically.